# Windows 8.1 ToggleSwitch - identify if user explicitly toggled

Tags: windows-8.1, toggleswitch

I am unable to distinguish if user explicitly toggle the toggle switch or if it was turned on / off programmatically. I need to set initial values for the toggleswitch when a popup is launched. And then later if user explicitly changes values, I need an event to be raised. 
So I tried to use the PointerReleased event on the ToggleSwitch instead of Toggled event but this does not get triggered on certain machines.

any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Thanks much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your ToggleSwitch in transparent Grid and set Tapped event handler to it. Tapped event will be raised only by user interaction. You'll also need to toggle it programatically inside Tapped event handler in order to mimic standard behavior.

```
<Grid Tapped="ToggleSwitchGrid_Tapped"
      Background="Transparent">
    <ToggleSwitch IsHitTestVisible="False" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

PointerReleased event can solve your problem. Just determine if it is left pointer like this:

```
void ToggleSwitch_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for input device
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        var properties = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Properties;
        if (properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            // Left button pressed
        }
        else if (properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
        {
            // Right button pressed
        }
    }
}
```